# How to adjust spacing between paragraphs in parbox?

Tags: spacing, lyx

What I have in LyX is this:

[image]

I've added to the preamble this line:

`\global\setlength{\parskip}{20pt}`

I am thus expecting a 20pt space between every line. However, this doesn't happen within the Parbox. My output:

[image]

**Question: What should I do to achieve the 20pt space between lines 3. and 4. above?** I would like this to be accomplished globally (i.e. across all Parboxes in my document).

LaTeX code (exported from LyX):

```
%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\global\setlength{\parskip}{20pt}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
1. Hi

2. Hi

\noindent{\fboxrule 3pt\fboxsep 6pt\fbox{\parbox[t]{1\columnwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}{%
3. Hi

4. Hi%
}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: aside from the use in `\parbox` note that the syntax `\global\setlength` is not guaranteed to make a global definition (and does not for example if the core `calc` package is loaded, as you have here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in  your user specified commands these:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\setlength{\parskip}{20pt}
\let\oldparbox\parbox
\renewcommand\parbox[3][t]{\oldparbox[#1]{#2}{\setlength{\parskip}{20pt}#3}}
\makeatother
```

**Edit: Thenext "PS" is wrong: (See David's comments)**
PS: I didn't really knew if the default optional parameter in parbox was `t`, but I looked for it and now I know it is. **These sentence between "bolds" is not true**

My Excuse: I just "googled" and had these results as first:

[image]

I saw the link with title `\parbox` and just read from the last two lines the above wrong sentence...

So, I learned the lesson... **Always double check your sources** and don't just trust what you see in google by a "distance"

Comment: Question: Am I supposed to replace the #1, #2, #3 with some numbers?

Comment: @KennyLJ Not at all! It is just a redefinition of `\parbox` command that takes 3 arguments (an optional and two mandatory). These numbers are references on the arguments of the command parbox that redefined to include the `parskip` redefinition inside `parbox` (private) environment

Comment: the default position for `\parbox` is `c` and this and chanes it to `t` removes all the other optional parameters for height and vertical position, also in general for a command with optional arguments the `\let\old...` form doesn't work although the optional arguments to parbox are done "by hand" not via `\newcommand` so you might get lucky.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found what I said here : http://herbert.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/html/latex2e/$5cparbox.html. Also,  started with `\def` but changed it to `\newcommand` after testing and show it works. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: the page that you reference shows that parbox has `\parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{text}`  ie it has three optional argumuments, and you have redefined it to have one, it also says `LaTeX will position a parbox so its centre lines up with the centre of the text line.` which isn't quite true but implies that the default is `c` although it then immediately contradicts itself by saying `(default is top). ` which is wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I provided the reason of my mistake in the answer.

Comment: @koleygr The default is `[c]`, not `[t]`.

Comment: @egreg... Do you mean I have to change it in my answer's code?

Comment: @koleygr Well, if you write that t is the default, it’s wrong.

Comment: @egreg: I explain in the previous sentence that this "PS" is wrong... Just left it there to not "destroy" the discussion here in the commements... Anyway, I will edit to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this is no direct answer to your question and certainly some overkill. However, if you want to draw boxes without shifting the text (in your example, 3 and 4 are shifted a bit to the left), you can always use Ti*k*Z overlays.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\global\setlength{\parskip}{20pt}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
1. Hi

2. Hi

3. Hi\tikznode{3}{\strut}

4. Hi\tikznode{4}{\strut}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node [fit=(current page text area.west|-4.south) (current page text
area.east|-3.north),draw,ultra thick,rectangle]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is certainly an overkill if you just want to draw these boxes, however if you want to do fancier things this may be a reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want the `\parskip` in every `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\normalparskip}
\setlength{\normalparskip}{20pt}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parskip}{\normalparskip}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\@parboxrestore}{\setlength{\parskip}{\normalparskip}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\framedparbox}[2][c]{%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{3pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}%
  \fbox{\parbox[#1]{\dimexpr1\columnwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}{#2}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

1. Hi

2. Hi

\framedparbox[t]{%
3. Hi

4. Hi%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]